# how to update column by adding +1 in android sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

i did search on internet could not find this problem solution

there is columns true answer and wrong answer.

If user select true answer in problem,column true answer should add +1 to perivious statement

how to that without select statement to read perivious value and add one?
just need quick and simple solution with update statement

Answer (score 0):

Consider executing this in a rawQuery:

```
UPDATE table_name SET Column = column + 1 WHERE ...
```